how to keep the directory tree for support files in l3build
Build project structure:
.
├── build.lua
├── support
│   └── pics
│       └── test.png
└── testfiles
    └── Test.pvt

build.lua is:
bundle = "TEST"
module = "mwe"

flatten = false
checksuppfiles = {"./pics/test.png"}
checkengines = {"pdftex"}
checkconfigs = {"build"}

The testfile Test.pvt is:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \includegraphics{./pics/test.png}
\end{document}

change to the root dir and run l3build save Test, the output log look like:
LaTeX Warning: File `./pics/test.png' not found on input line 5.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pics/test.png' not found: using draft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.5   \includegraphics{./pics/test.png}

The picture Test.png not found, check the test folder structure in ./build/. It is:
./build/test
├── ascii.tcx
├── Test.log
├── Test.pdf
├── Test.pdftex.aux
├── test.png
├── Test.pvt
└── Test.tpf

l3build doese not keep the directory tree for the support file, that is why Test.png can not been found. But i have already set flatten to false. In the l3build.pdf i see:

Switch to flatten any source structure when sending to CTAN

Does that means the flatten variable can only been used for sending to CTAN not for l3build save ? Then, how to keep the dirctory tree ?

The supportdir is for 'general' support files, and is always flattened: files here are for '(La)TeX to run'. You are wanting a file for a test specifically - that does in testsuppdir, for example testfiles/support/testpath: see how this is done for l3kernel, which does need to test file path inclusion.

The design of placing these specific test support files in ./testfiles/support/pics is much more reasonable and understandable than put in ./support/pics. Thank you !
